# Timer Task rung in background Javascript or Cordova App

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm looking forward to implement reminder application using cordova. I'm looking for a posibility to implement background task using javascript. Even the application is not active it should run in background. Is this task  possible with java script or Do I need to develop a plugin using Cordova (Android & IOs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is not possible to do background work when the app (browser is not active) so I found a great library for cordova

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Answer (score 4):

I did not found ways to manage background tasks using javascript. Here are few related link to do cordova plugins

- https://github.com/jocull/phonegap-backgroundjs
- https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service

BR

Richard